# why processlist list shows limited threads

Tags: mysql, performance

Actually I have set **max_connection** value set to **500** but processes shows only **266** i.e when I run
**show full processlist** it shows only 266 processes not more than this however my connection value is 500.

I analyzed every query and found that every query is using single table there is no query which is using 2 tables.

Is any other settings which I am missing? Please suggest on this.Why it is showing only 266 processes?

Comment: As this question is not about programming, it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO deals with database internals questions like this one.

Comment: How do you think you know you currently have more than 266 connections?

Comment: You should ask this on [dba.se]

Comment: @user207421 when I ran show full processlist it shows only 266 processes

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your results to say that only 266 connections existed at that moment.  (If there aren't 500 users trying to connect, there won't be 500 rows in the processlist.)

Were you getting some error from other attempted connections not being accepted?  If so, what was the exact text of the error message.

266 connections, each *running* a query, is a problem.  I highly recommend you find the full text of the query (or queries) involved.  `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` may be useful if the queries were truncated.  Then show us the query, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It is likely that some new `INDEX` (possibly composite)` would make them run faster -- and you might never see as many as 266 again.